# Flutter Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, flutter

After i updated XCode to version 9 i always get a big list of mostly the same errors when i want to start the app in an IOS 11 simulator. So far i didn't tested an earlier ios version but ios 10 worked perfectly before the XCode update.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone X in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Sep 21 22:35:18 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.videosubscriptionsd): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Sep 21 22:35:18 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.ServerDocuments.ServerFileProvider): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:18 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.ServerDocuments.ServerFileProvider): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 21 22:35:18 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:18 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Sep 21 22:35:18 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 21 22:35:18 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.AssetCacheLocatorService): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:18 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.AssetCacheLocatorService): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 21 22:35:18 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.StreamingUnzipService): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:18 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.StreamingUnzipService): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.WebKit.Networking): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.WebKit.Networking): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.intents.intents-image-service): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.intents.intents-image-service): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.WebKit.Databases): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.WebKit.Databases): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.DictionaryServiceHelper): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.DictionaryServiceHelper): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.AnnotationKit.MigratorService): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.AnnotationKit.MigratorService): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.WebKit.WebContent): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.WebKit.WebContent): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.AssetCacheLocatorService): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.AssetCacheLocatorService): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.Photos.CPLDiagnose): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.Photos.CPLDiagnose): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.StreamingUnzipService): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.StreamingUnzipService): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.uifoundation-bundle-helper): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.uifoundation-bundle-helper): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.Safari.ImageDecoder): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.Safari.ImageDecoder): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.Safari.History): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.Safari.History): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.FileProvider.LocalStorage): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.FileProvider.LocalStorage): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.CloudDocsDaemon.container-metadata-extractor): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.CloudDocsDaemon.container-metadata-extractor): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.mobileslideshow.PhotosFileProvider): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:19 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.mobileslideshow.PhotosFileProvider): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 21 22:35:20 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.intents.intents-image-service): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:20 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.intents.intents-image-service): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 21 22:35:20 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:20 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
Sep 21 22:35:20 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 21 22:35:20 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.DictionaryServiceHelper): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:20 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.DictionaryServiceHelper): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 21 22:35:20 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.AssetCacheLocatorService): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:20 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.AssetCacheLocatorService): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 21 22:35:20 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.Photos.CPLDiagnose): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:20 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.Photos.CPLDiagnose): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 21 22:35:20 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.StreamingUnzipService): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:20 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.StreamingUnzipService): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Sep 21 22:35:20 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.uifoundation-bundle-helper): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Sep 21 22:35:20 Lukass-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.8EADD4B6-5B22-4172-8A40-C8EE4D533825[5282] (com.apple.uifoundation-bundle-helper): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
```

The Standard app which gets generated by "flutter create app" runs but the big issue list get displayed. But if i run my other app it crashes with these errors. Is this an known problem and is there an fix?

Comment: I am getting similar errors too, even when I try to run their stock apps. Are you able to run Safari, Photo apps in the iOS 11 simulator? It keeps crashing on all iOS 11 simulator devices. It's fine if I run the iOS 9.2. simulator though.

My problem here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46430608/xcode-9-ios-11-simulator-all-apps-crashing

Did you figure out a fix for it?

Comment: I'm getting the same error for IOS 11 simulator, `(com.apple.WebKit.WebContent): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit` , it works fine for lower IOS versions, any solutions? coud it be IOS 11 bug?

Answer (score 3):

For all who also face this problem here my solution:

I did this steps:

Follow the Xcode signing flow to provision your project:Open the default Xcode workspace in your project by running **open ios/Runner.xcworkspace** in a terminal window from your Flutter project directory.In Xcode, select the Runner project in the left navigation panel.In the Runner target settings page, make sure your Development Team is selected under General > Signing > Team. When you select a team, Xcode creates and downloads a Development Certificate, registers your device with your account, and creates and downloads a provisioning profile (if needed).

With these steps i solved the problem which i mentioned in my question but another problem came up.

Edit: 
I solved all this problems after i uninstalled flutter and cloned the repo again but this time the master branch not the alpha which is mentioned at the getting started tutorial on the flutter page.

From flutter page:
git clone -b alpha https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

Fix:
git clone -b master https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

Comment: I'm using `Xamarin` and I don't think your solution works for me. It was working fine before I upgrade to IOS 11, thanks for sharing your solutions though

Comment: They &quot;unknown key for boolean&quot; problem disapeared and the app does not crash anymore but now i face the problem that i cant hot reload anymore. But if you say you face the same problem with Xamarian then Apple changed something in there simulators

Comment: My problem now is that the terminal says me : "(com.apple.videosubscriptionsd): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds."