# Xcode 9 iOS 10 / 11 Simulators - All Apps Crashing

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, ios11, xcode9

I just installed Xcode 9 and tried running the iOS 11 and 10.3.1 simulators.

Weirdly, ALL the stock apps in the simulator are crashing / force closing the moment I click on any of them, i.e. Safari, Photos, etc.

I've tried it on iPhone X, iPhone 8/8+ and iPhone 6+ simulators with iOS 11 / 10.3.1, all with the same crashing result. If I try it on older iOS simulators such as iPhone 6+ iOS 9.2, then it runs fine.

If I try to launch it many times, i.e. 40 - 50 times for Safari or Calendar, *sometimes* that specific app may run, and once successfully ran, it'll remain so for the rest of the session (until I close the app at the task switcher, then same problem recurs). The same happens for my Xcode compiled app too.

I saw many of these errors in the simulator's device logs, not sure if it's relevant:

---

> Sep 26 23:25:34 MYMAC
>   com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.2F950F5F-6057-4AAA-A5B4-A8068A8F00F9[10215]
>   (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for
>   Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
>
> Sep 26 23:25:33 MYMAC
>   com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.2F950F5F-6057-4AAA-A5B4-A8068A8F00F9[10215]
>   (com.apple.Safari.History): Unknown key for Boolean:
>   EnableTransactions
>
> Sep 26 23:25:33 MYMAC
>   com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.2F950F5F-6057-4AAA-A5B4-A8068A8F00F9[10215]
>   (com.apple.icloud.FMF.FMFMapXPCService): Unknown key for Boolean:
>   EnableTransactions
>
> Sep 26 23:25:34 MYMAC
>   com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.2F950F5F-6057-4AAA-A5B4-A8068A8F00F9[10215]
>   (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for
>   Boolean: EnableTransactions

---

My iMac 2009 has been running El Capitan and Xcode 8 fine all the while, and I just upgraded to High Sierra with Xcode 9. I also updated to iTunes 12.7, in case that makes a difference.

I also tried running my old Xcode 8 (still installed as separate copy) and iOS 10.3.1 simulators, these stock apps run fine.

So this problem seems to happen only with Xcode 9 and iOS 10/11 simulators.

Can anyone shed some light on this problem please? Thank you.

Comment: Try updating to Xcode 9.1?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've tried the Xcode 9.1 Beta too, but same problem persisted. I also see many such errors in the Xcode Console when launching stock apps: "[com.apple.Preferences] Bootstrap failed with error: <NSError: 0x600000846c60; domain: BKSProcessErrorDomain; code: 1 (bootstrap-failed); reason: "Unable to obtain valid process handle">". Do you know that this means?

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46260005/341994 Also I always delete DerivedData and _~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode_.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I've just tried deleting all simulators, DerivedData and com.apple.dt.Xcode, but the same problem persisted. The strange thing is if I repeatedly try to launch a stock / own app for like 40 - 50 times, it'll likely start up fine eventually. But if I kill the app, same problem repeats.

Comment: Well, presumably you're getting the crash dialog and hitting Report every time, so Apple knows this is happening. :)

Comment: This specific error is a red-herring. Look in Console, under User Reports. That's where crash reports from Simulator apps will show up. Please file a bug report and attach a sysdiagnose, those crash reports, and the output of `xcrun simctl diagnose`.

Answer (score 1):

You asked in my similar question if i found an solution. I guess i found one.

I set the Dev Team in Xcode on the Flutter Page the describe how to.

From the Flutter Page:

Follow the Xcode signing flow to provision your project:Open the default Xcode workspace in your project by running **open ios/Runner.xcworkspace** in a terminal window from your Flutter project directory.In Xcode, select the Runner project in the left navigation panel.In the Runner target settings page, make sure your Development Team is selected under General > Signing > Team. When you select a team, Xcode creates and downloads a Development Certificate, registers your device with your account, and creates and downloads a provisioning profile (if needed)

But then i run in an other error which dont let me hot reload anymore

Edit: Reinstall flutter but this time clone the master branch not the alpha.

So follow the steps on the flutter page but change this word in the first step:

Old:
git clone -b alpha https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

New:
git clone -b master https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution. I'll try around and see if I can adapt your solution to my problem. My simulator's force-close error happens even without running an app, just by clicking on the default apps there.